# Font Awesome restrictions with the CSS path?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Font Awesome worked fine when I had index.html at the root with a link to font-awesome.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

I changed the structure of my website for having multiple languages and I now have a folder called /en for all the pages in English and a folder called /de for all pages in German.
I hence have /en/index.html

When I write in the head of index.html following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

then I get small boxes with numbers, like f086 instead of the icon comments for example.
It means, the font-awesome.css file is found but the icons do not appear.

I tried to put the folder font-awesome in en/test/ and wrote in /en/index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

and it works again.

Are there some restrictions in the path of the css file font-awesome.css?
Is it possible to change them or are there other ways of solving that problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have right paths? Probably a path to CSS from a index.html file is wrong. For example "../" means one directory up and then /assets/plugins/..etc. Open source code with Firefox and click on the CSS path. If CSS file is opened then path is correct.

Comment: There aren't any restrictions on the paths. You must be setting them incorrectly. Are you positive that the paths to the font files themselves are correct?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct but it does not work!

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the problem. I was doing something wrong with apache and php. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem. I was doing something wrong with apache and php.

While displaying the pages on the browser, the icons did not appear,
and opening them via `http://localhost/en/index.html` solved the problem.

Sorry, my mistake.